# Mongoose: Adding an element to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, nodes

I'm using [Drywall](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall/) to create a website.

I'm trying to add a dashboard element to the accounts section of the admin site. The dashboard element is to store an array of dashboards (strings) that the user has access to.

I've managed to successfully add the "dashboards" into the schema and store data in it.

Here's the problem: 
I need to be able to add elements to the array. The way the code stands currently replaces the contents of `dashboards` in the database.

I know I can use `$addToSet`, but I'm not sure how I'd do that since the fieldsToSet variable is sent to the `findByIdAndUpdate()` method as a single object.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
workflow.on('patchAccount', function() {
var fieldsToSet = {
  name: {
    first: req.body.first,
    middle: req.body.middle,
    last: req.body.last,
    full: req.body.first +' '+ req.body.last
  },
  company: req.body.company,
  phone: req.body.phone,
  zip: req.body.zip,
  search: [
    req.body.dashboards,
    req.body.first,
    req.body.middle,
    req.body.last,
    req.body.company,
    req.body.phone,
    req.body.zip,
  ]
};

req.app.db.models.Account.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, fieldsToSet, function(err, account) {
  if (err) {
    return workflow.emit('exception', err);
  }

  workflow.outcome.account = account;
  return workflow.emit('response');
 }); 
});
```

Here's a link to the original [file](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall/blob/master/views/admin/accounts/index.js): (lines 184-203)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`fieldsToSet` is a bad name (at least misleading in this case), the parameter is actually `update` which can take $actions like $addToSet

I don't think you want to set (only) the search field with dashboards.  I'm guessing that field is used to index users for a search.  So you'll probably wind up doing something like this:

```
fieldsToSet = {
   ....all the regular stuff,
   $addToSet: {dashboard: req.body.dashboardToAdd}  
                          //I'm not sure that you can add multiple values at once
}
```

Since this is setting all of the values each time I'm not sure you actually will want to add single dashboard items.  Instead you might want to get the full set of dashboards the user has and set the whole array again anyway (what if they removed one?)

```
fieldsToSet = {
   ....all the regular stuff,
   dashboards: req.body.dashboards
                          //In this case you'd want to make sure dashboards is an appropriate array
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was actually a really stupid problem; I forgot commas in the server side script when I added dashboards....